# ASP.NET Outlook Appointment scheduling

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, outlook, integration

Hai TEchies

Can anyone tell me how can i set an appointment /reminder in the outlook express , from my ASP.NET web page. I am using ASP.NET 2.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is an .ics attachment for email.  This requires you to create specifically crafted text file with an .ics extension and attach that to your email.

A quick google for "asp.net ics" brings up:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/SendAppointment.aspx
which seems suitable to your needs.[WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) also has a link on this.

Stackoverflow also has this tag that has more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/icalendar

Answer (score -1):

Something like [this](http://www.aspnetemail.com/help/aspnetemail.calendaring.icalendar.html) using the iCal standard will probably work.  It will also work with Google Calendar.